# Calling constructor from another class

Tags: c++, constructor, sse

If I have a class like this:

```
typedef union { __m128 quad; float numbers[4]; } Data

class foo
{
public:
    foo() : m_Data() {}

    Data m_Data;
};
```

and a class like this:

```
class bar
{
public:

   bar() : m_Data() {}

   foo m_Data;
}
```

is foo's constructor called when making an instance of bar?

Because when I try to use `bar`'s `m_Data`'s `quad` in `bar` it seems to be uninitialized, even though it has values in `numbers[4]`. :\

Specifically, this crashes:

```
m_Data.quad = _mm_mul_ps(m_Data.quad, a_Other.m_Data.quad)
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: On an unrelated note, your union trick is probably going to hurt performance. You're introducing a lot of potential aliasing which the compiler has to account for and work around, right in the middle of your (presumably performance-critical) SIMD code.

Comment: You'll have to post a more complete example. You say "bar's m_Data's quad in bar it seems to be uninitialized, even though it has values in numbers[4]" the code you posted never sets it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your constructor to be `public`, otherwise you are not allowing anyone to instantiate your class if you declare it as `private` member.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good for me. foo and bar are non-POD types because they have a constructor, so their members are guaranteed to be initialized after constructing.

Maybe the data is overwritten later through a memory leak?

How do you create the instance of bar?